# How to save file.txt with JFileChooser?

Tags: java, save, jfilechooser, notepad

I am developing notepad project, would like know how do for save a file.txt, my problem is, I keep the file opening JFileChooser, after selected the local where save intend, but after if save again will open JFileChoose again. I want save. Not save as.

```
  JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

    int resp = fc.showSaveDialog(fc);

    if (resp == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        PrintStream fileOut = null;
        try {

            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();

            fileOut = new PrintStream(file);

            fileOut.print(txtArea.getText());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(frmNotePad.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {

            fileOut.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you work flow.

Basically, when you first save the file, you need to keep a reference to the `File` to which you saved to...

```
public class ... {
   private File currentFile;
```

Now, when you go to save the file, you need to check if the `currentFile` is `null` or not.  It it is `null`, you ask the user to select a file, otherwise, you can go ahead and try and save the file...

```
if (currentFile == null) {

    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    int resp = fc.showSaveDialog(fc);

    if (resp == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        currentFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
    }

}

// Used to make sure that the user didn't cancel the JFileChooser
if (currentFile != null) {
    PrintStream fileOut = null;
    try {
        fileOut = new PrintStream(file);
        fileOut.print(txtArea.getText());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(frmNotePad.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (IOException exp) {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a save as an alternate to a save as, have the program store a File object referencing the currently opened file's path so the program is always aware of what it's editing, then just write to the programs file variable